# How to rename dot filenames in python

Tags: python, glob, os.path

In GIT, we have a file called .gitignore, what is the technical term to call them, (are files like these valid to be called as "filename"), What are they supposed to be called?

I have written a simple script in python to change the name of files, however, Python doesn't seem to recognize folders and files that starts with a dot (.) such as .git, .gitignore etc

```
import os
import glob
rootdir = 'C:\\INBOX\\POLINATE\\JUNKS\\**'

# #work on files
for filename in glob.iglob(rootdir, recursive=True):
    
    if os.path.isfile(filename): # filter dirs        
        print(filename)

        try:                
            ##rename
            new_filename = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(14)).lower()
            new_extension = new_filename[0:3]
            final_name = os.path.dirname(filename) + os.sep + new_filename+'.'+new_extension
            os.rename(filename,final_name)
            print(final_name)

        except Exception as e:
            #raise e            
            print(e)
```

Script above works for files with Xn.3 format (Xn filenames within allowable range including spaces).(Three (3) letter extension) but it leaves files starting with a dot (.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Files starting with `.` are mainly hidden files that you don't need in many cases.

In your case `.git` and `.gitignore` are the supporting files for git operations. Actually your program dont need these files to run.
`.gitattributes` files contains your git informations and `.gitignore`  file tells git to ignore the git supporting files.

You can see a `.vs` file in the same folder. I assume you are using vscode and it might be the information files of vscode.